# Two time in DataGridView and get the timespan (HOW?)

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I'm new on timespan and I don't know how to work with this. Well, I tried but I failed to get what I want. I have two timespans from DataGridView and converted them to DateTime, I want to change the background color of the second "time" if it's less or more than 9 hours. Sorry if my English is not good.

| Date In | Time In | Date Out | Time Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/23/2022 | 21:00:00 | 03/24/2022 | 05:12:12 |
| 03/24/2022 | 21:00:00 | 03/25/2022 | 07:08:16 |

if less than 9 hours, the back color is red.

if more than 9 hours, the back color is green.

Here is my code, I want to see first the red color before I write the green color.

```
Private Sub DataGridView6_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView6.CellFormatting
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 And e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim startTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Value.ToString())
            If e.ColumnIndex = 3 And e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim endTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Value.ToString())
                Dim totalTime As TimeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime)
                Dim validity As DateTime = totalTime.Hours & totalTime.Minutes & totalTime.Seconds
                If totalTime < TimeSpan.FromHours(9) Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance. ^_^ I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: If the Type of the Columns is actually TimeSpan, don't convert to string and don't convert to DateTime. You can perform that operation on TimeSpan objects directly. If the Type is String, then use `TimeSpan.TryParse()`, specifying the correct `CultureInfo`, if you set a specific (fixed) Format for that Column.

Comment: Is the  datasource of your datagridview a datatable and are the columns of DateTime data type?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, @Jimi Thanks for replying. Yes, the columns named "Time In" and "Time Out" are actually TimeSpan but the dates are DateTime. Am I able to get the span of two times without their dates?

Comment: Hi, @F0r3v3r-A-N00b. The first and third columns are DateTime but the second and fourth columns are TimeSpan.

Comment: If less than 9 hours, the background color of the time-out column will become red. If more than 9 hours, the background color of the time-out will become green.

Comment: @Jimi, how am I going to perform the operation correctly, is my 3rd "If" from the Sub is correct? Or do I need to change it? I'm so sorry for this.

Comment: First of all, you need to post the precise DataSource of your DataGridView. Then, the `If` condition is clearly wrong: you have `If e.ColumnIndex = 1  [...] If e.ColumnIndex = 3 end if  [...] end if` -> the `ColumnIndex` cannot be both `1` and `3` at the same time. - Then, if the Value (the content) of a Cell is of Type `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`, cast to that Type, for sure not `String`. You format data (as a string) for presentation (to reflect a Culture's date/time format here), not to work with it. Never convert to string to *work* with dates, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Your are very close to the required results. All you have to do is declare the datatable columns as string and store dates & times in sql-format. And while formatting the cells, concatenate the date and time columns as following: -

```
dt = New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("DATE_IN", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("TIME_IN", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("DATE_OT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("TIME_OT", Type.GetType("System.String"))

rw = dt.NewRow()
rw("DATE_IN") = "2022-03-29"
rw("TIME_IN") = "21:00:00"
rw("DATE_OT") = "2022-03-30"
rw("TIME_OT") = "05:12:12"
dt.Rows.Add(rw)

rw = dt.NewRow()
rw("DATE_IN") = "2022-03-30"
rw("TIME_IN") = "21:00:00"
rw("DATE_OT") = "2022-03-31"
rw("TIME_OT") = "07:08:16"
dt.Rows.Add(rw)

dgvLDR.DataSource = dt

Private Sub dgvLDR_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvLDR.CellFormatting
   Dim sTimeIn, sTimeOt As DateTime
   Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvLDR.Rows(e.RowIndex)

   Try
       sTimeIn = dgvRow.Cells("DATE_IN").Value & " " & dgvRow.Cells("TIME_IN").Value
       sTimeOt = dgvRow.Cells("DATE_OT").Value & " " & dgvRow.Cells("TIME_OT").Value

       Dim totalTime As TimeSpan = sTimeOt.Subtract(sTimeIn)

       If totalTime < TimeSpan.FromHours(9) Then
           dgvRow.Cells("TIME_OT").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
       Else
           dgvRow.Cells("TIME_OT").Style.BackColor = Color.Green
       End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, sir, I will try this. I had some trouble with my IDE so I need to rearrange my project. Thank you so much, sir.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm having some trouble with the data types that I have in my data table. I have Date data types in the first and third columns and timespan in the second and fourth columns. But I'm working on it. Thank you very much for your reply, sir. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I will cast a vote on your answer once I have the privilege to vote. Thanks again. ^_^